# Why isn't siunitx literal input typeset the same way as 'interpreted' input

Tags: siunitx

Why doesn't \squared and ^2 give the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}  
test:\\
\qty[per-mode = fraction]{4.91}{\m\per\s\squared}\\
\qty[per-mode = fraction]{4.91}{\m\per\s^2}\\
\qty[per-mode = fraction]{4.91}{m/s^2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use “shorthands” if you want that `per-mode` does the correct parsing.